# Associate Eclipse with src (.java) files in windows 7

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way that you can associate Eclipse with the file extension .java in Windows? So that when I double click the file in windows explorer or total commander it automaticly opens the .java file in Eclipse for viewing and editing. Similar to visual studio when you click c# .cs files or any other type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click on .java file. Then click on Properties and then change Open With option. Now a dialog window will be shown and you only have to find your eclipse.exe in the dialog box.

Comment: Actually it doesn't *really* work as expected. Every time you try to open a file like that, a new instance of Eclipse gets launched. But the workspace cannot be shared across multiple instances. Many programs detect that and "merge" the open process within the active instancs, which sometimes results in a new tab opening with the new file. It's Eclipse's fault, because it can't handle multiple to single instance, but associating Java files to eclipse.exe is quite useless when you are actively developing. Better drag the file into Eclipse window

Answer (score 1):

THere are two methods to do this simply:

```
right click on .java file > open with > eclipse > check 'set as default program'
```

or access it via control panel (not sure about which option under which folder. Try the 'default programs' menu

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Right Click-> Open with-> other-> Eclipse?

Comment: tnx. at first it didnt have an option Open With, only Open. when I clicked Open then I selected "Select a program from a list of installed programs" and through browse i associated it with eclipse :)